Firth logistic regression with random effects
Is there any way to implement Firth's logistic regression while introducing random effects ?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Firth not frith?

I am confident about spelling. I am not confident this is a clear question. Are you asking abiut statistical principle or coding in some software.

It is a bit unclear whether you are asking a statistical question here (which would be great), or whether you are just asking for software recommendations (which would be off-topic here). Assuming the former, I think you might be able to achieve this by fitting an initial logistic logistic mixed effects model to obtain initial estimates. Then, define a custom penalised log-likelihood function that incorporates both Firth's correction and the random effects. Finally, optimise this combined model using the initial estimates from the GLMM as starting values.
